# Mapeamento fluent chave composta nhibernate com banco firebird

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, chave-composta

Galera estou com dificuldade no mapeamento de chave primaria composta usando fluent nhibernate. Tenho a classe a seguir:

```
 public class NotaItem
{
    public NotaItem(){}

    public virtual int Id { get; set; } //chave primaria
    public virtual Int16 NumeroSequencialItem { get; set; } //chave primaria
    public virtual Int16 NumeroOrdem { get; set; }
}
```

Mapeamento:

```
 public class NotaItemMap : ClassMap<NotaItem>
{
    public NotaItemMap()
    {
        Table("NOTITEM");

        //Chave primária
        CompositeId().KeyReference(x => x.Id, "NOTIT_ID")
       .KeyProperty(x =>  x.NumeroSequencialItem, "NOTIT_NR_SEQUENCIAL_ITEM");

        Map(x => x.NumeroOrdem)
       .Column("NOTIT_NR_ORDEM")
       .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de fazer essa implementação, pois dessa forma não está funcionando. 
Obs: Os campos de chave primaria não é auto incremento.

Log de exceção: Execeção :

> FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or
>   incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory.
>   Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
>
> ---> FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or
>   incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory.
>   Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
>
> ---> NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping
>   document: (XmlDocument) ---> NHibernate.MappingException: composite-id
>   class must override Equals():
>   TreinamentoNHibernate.Core.Entidade.NotaItem    em
>   NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.ClassCompositeIdBinder.CheckEqualsAndGetHashCodeOverride()
>   em
>   NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.ClassCompositeIdBinder.BindCompositeId(HbmCompositeId
>   idSchema, PersistentClass rootClass)    em
>   NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.RootClassBinder.Bind(HbmClass
>   classSchema, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)    em
>   NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.AddEntitiesMappings(HbmMapping
>   mappingSchema, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)    em
>   NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.Bind(HbmMapping
>   mappingSchema)    em
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMapping
>   mappingDocument, String documentFileName)    --- Fim do rastreamento
>   de pilha de exceções internas ---    em
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception)    em
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMapping
>   mappingDocument, String documentFileName)    em
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ProcessMappingsQueue()    em
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream,
>   String name)    em
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDocument(XmlDocument doc, String name)
>   em NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDocument(XmlDocument doc)    em
>   FluentNHibernate.PersistenceModel.Configure(Configuration cfg)    em
>   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.MappingConfiguration.Apply(Configuration cfg)
>   em FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration()
>   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---    em FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration()    em
>   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()    ---
>   Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---    em
>   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()    em
>   TreinamentoNHibernate.Data.SessionFactory.SessionFactoryUtil..cctor()
>   na
>   E:\VisualCSharp\Projects\TreinamentoNHibernate\TreinamentoNHibernate.Data\SessionFactory\SessionFactoryUtil.cs:linha
>   46

Comment: Qual o problema você está com a implementação atual?

Comment: O que está dando de errado que você esperava um resultado diferente? Seu mapeamento das chaves compostas, no que pude observar, esta correto!

Comment: Pode [editar a pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/111337/edit) com o log do erro ao iniciar a sessão?

Comment: A exceção é levantada ao buscar dados do banco.

Comment: Fiz um teste implementando com chave simples: 
Id(t => t.Id).Column("NOTIT_ID");
troquei a linha inteira do "CompositeId()" por essa acima e funcionou. Não deu exceção!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Problema esta descrito no log do *stack* de erro na seguinte linha: `composite-id class must override Equals()`, onde para você utilizar e mapear um `CompositeId` (chave composta) em seu mapeamento, você deve sobrescrever o `Equals()` de sua entidade, fazendo com que ele represente as chaves compostas de forma unica.

No seu caso algo assim:

```
// override object.Equals
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
    {
        return false;
    }

    NotaItem other = obj as NotaItem;
    if (other == null)
        return false;
    if (Id == other.Id && NumeroSequencialItem == other.NumeroSequencialItem)
        return true;
    return base.Equals(obj);
}
```

Comment: Vlw cara, muito obrigado.. Funcionou.. Isso mesmo que precisava. Venho do java e estou começando agora com C#.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius, bom que resolveu! Se realmente resolveu sua questão você pode marcar a resposta como resolvida, e como você parece ser novo aqui de uma olhada [nisso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) e [nisso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

Para uma chave composta, a resposta acima quase atende ao problema;

tem outra solução, assim:

**Entidade**

```
    public class ItemNota
    {
        public virtual int NumeroNota { get; set; }
        public virtual Int32 Serie { get; set; }
        public virtual int Sequencial { get; set; }


        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as ItemNota;

            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

            return this.NumeroNota == other.NumeroNota && this.Serie == other.Serie && this.Sequencial == other.Sequencial;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = GetType().GetHashCode();
                hash = (hash * 31) ^ this.NumeroNota.GetHashCode();
                hash = (hash * 31) ^ this.Serie.GetHashCode();
                hash = (hash * 31) ^ this.Sequencial.GetHashCode();

                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Mapeamento**

```
    public class ItemNotaMap : ClassMap<ItemNota>
    {
        public ItemNotaMap ()
        {
            CompositeId()
               .KeyProperty(c => c.NumeroNota, "oennotnum")
               .KeyProperty(c => c.Serie, "oennotser")
               .KeyProperty(c => c.Sequencial, "oenseq");

         ...     

            Table("itemnota");
        }
    }
```