# Mapeamento NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Como faço o mapeamento de uma tabela que possui chave composta no NHibernate?

Por exemplo: tenho uma tabela chamada `configuracao`. Esta tabela possui uma referencia para a tabela `local_estoque`. Normalmente um mapeamento ficaria assim:

```
References(x => x.Local_Estoque_Ordem_Servico, "id_local_ordem_servico");
```

Porém, na tabela `local_estoque` a chave primária é composta `("id_filial" e "id_local_estoque)`. Como fica o mapeamento para este caso?

Comment: Veja o override na classe equals citado na resposta desta pergunta para resolver isto da chave composta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111337/mapeamento-fluent-chave-composta-nhibernate-com-banco-firebird

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso

CompositeId()
    .KeyReference(x => x.FilialId, "id_filial")
    .KeyReference(x => x.LocalId, "id_local");